# jQuery Drag-n-Drop issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two div elements 1. div (id="draggable") & div (id="dropper"). each of them contains several div inside them. I want to drag and drop child  from draggable to dropper. After I did that I want to move them around in the dropper. So far I have managed to do all the things, but I can't achieve the last part. Because the child  from the draggable can move in whole document. can anyone pls help me to do this?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>New Web Project</title>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.9.0.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="draggable" class="drop">
        <h4>Drag From Here</h4>
        <div id="wrapper1" class="floatLeft">item1 </div> 
        <div id="wrapper2" class="floatLeft">item2 </div> 
        <div id="wrapper3" class="floatLeft">item3 </div> 
        <div id="wrapper4" class="floatLeft">item4 </div> 

    </div>

    <div id="dropper" class="drop">
        <h4>Drop'em here</h4>
        <div class="floatLeft">item1 </div> 
        <div class="floatLeft">item2 </div> 
        <div class="floatLeft">item3 </div> 
        <div class="floatLeft">item4 </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

```
#draggable{
height:100px;
border-style:solid;
border-bottom-color:black;
margin-right: 10px;
}


.floatLeft{
    float:left;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#dropper{
height: 80px;
/*width: 50%;*/
border-style:solid;
border-bottom-color:black;
margin-right: 10px;
}


$(function(){


$("#draggable").each(function(){

    $("#draggable div").draggable();
}   

);


$("#dropper").droppable(

);

$("#dropper div").draggable({ containment: "parent" });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you expect a dropped item to automatically be inserted in the DOM structure of the droppable - but that's not the case.
And that's why your code doesn't give you what you want.
However, there's the sortable plugin that might be what you're looking for. The fact that the dropped div will be integrated in the target's DOM structure makes it easy to meet your requirement:

```
$("#draggable").sortable ({
    connectWith: "#dropper",
    items: "> div"
});
$("#dropper").sortable({
    containment: "parent",
    items: "> div"
});
```

Click the link to see a [jsfiddle that uses the sortable plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/VYRSg/1/)